# Android decode Ukrainian characters

Tags: android, character, decode

I am getting these characters as a JSON response :

[image: 1]

This characters should be translated to Ukrainian word Активная

How can I decode this set of characters, tried it with java URLDecoder, no luck so far, any ideas ?

Comment: it is html/xml encoding ... but there is no need for this as utf-8 supports cyrillic script ... if you have access to backend just fix it on server side

Comment: create JSONObject from your response, him decoded himself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is [XML entity encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview). Use an XML parser or `Html.fromHtml()` to decode it.

Also, consider fixing the server side to use JSON `\uNNNN` encoding for character literals instead.